# Find function given power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to find the function given the power series?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{(n+1)}}(x-2)^n$$

Comment: Hint: geometric series.

Comment: Hint. Start from the geometric series and try to make it match this one.

Answer (score 2):

Write as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2-x}{2}\right)^n
$$
and use the formula for a geometric series.